# Slow JSONSerialization Parsing Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization

I'm building an application able to return books info (Title,Description,Author ...) using Google Books Api.

The problem is that after detecting ISBN (International Standard Book Number)from the previous view it takes time to show details on my current view.

[image]

After 1-3 seconds I get parsing result:

[image]

I'm using this method to get data using google books api:

```
func getBookInfo(isbn: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:\(isbn)") else {
        print("***********************************")
        print("the url is not valid")
        return
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(response)
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("no error but no data")
            print("***********************************")
            print(response)
            return
        }
        guard let jsonResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) else {
            print("the JSON is not valid")
            return
        }


        if let arrayOfLa = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.language") as? [String] {

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("opopopop")
                    print (arrayOfLa)

                }
            }

        }




        ///finish language
        if let arrayOfTitles = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.title") as? [String] {

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.title = "\(arrayOfTitles[0])"

                }
            }

        }
        if let arrayOfDesc = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.description") as? [String] {



            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.bookDescription.text =  "\(arrayOfDesc[0])"
                }
            }



        }

        //start here 

        if let arrayOfPictures = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail") as? [String] {

            print ("\(arrayOfPictures[0])")
            self.bookPicture = "\(arrayOfPictures[0])"
            if let checkedUrl = URL(string: "\(arrayOfPictures[0])") {
                self.imageBook.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                self.downloadImage(url: checkedUrl)
            }
                           }




        //end here

        //start author here

        if let arrayOfAuthors = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.authors") as? [[String]]  {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.authorText.text =  "\((arrayOfAuthors[0])[0])"
                }
            }

        }

        // finish author here
        //start categories here

        if let arrayOfCategories = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.categories") as? [[String]]  {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
                DispatchQueue.main.async {


                    self.categorieText.text =  "\((arrayOfCategories[0])[0])"                 }
            }

        }

        // finish caetegories here




    }).resume()
}
```

and I'm calling it on the ViewWillAppaer

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    getBookInfo(isbn: isbnCode)
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Perhaps the delay is because of a slow response from the Google Books API?

Comment: It also might be that your `downloadImage` function is blocking things from being rendered.

Comment: I comment my downloadImage function and nothing changes, will see with Google Books API response time and back again, thank you